# jquery datepicker icon stretched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I can't seem to solve a problem with jquery datepicker icon getting stretched, it looks like this:

[image: Stretched icon]

When the original icon is `17x17` pixels, and looks like this:

[image: the actual png image]

I am attaching this image via `input` element in the code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="searchDate" id="searchDate" class="datePickerWithImage" cth:inputvalidate="Date" size="10" maxlength="10" tabIndex="14" title="Provide value for search date" />
```

And the `jquery` function for the datepicker is:

```
$( ".datePickerWithImage" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    buttonImage: "/images/manageschedule.png",
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    buttonText: "Open calendar",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showWeek: true,
});
```

And it has some additional rendering hints in css:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
                       margin-left:2px;
                       }
```

I can't seem to find anything helpful in the jquery api for this, and it just looks grotesque that I really want to fix it :)

Edit: In developer tools I can see element as `<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 127.909px; left: 471.349px; z-index: 2; display: none;">`.. But not sure how helpful that really is..

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle

Comment: Your _provided_ code works perfectly as [tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/6cexw2r3/), Have a look at your inspect element, there is probably a CSS that is causing that issue.

Comment: @AhsN hmm, it seems to work fine indeed in the fiddle.. strange. I added the inspect element output to the question, but it doesn't seem to shed more light on this..

Comment: @julumme In the inspect element view, check the CSS properties that are being applied to the icon. Check/Uncheck the CSS properties attached to it until you find the one that causing the issue.

Comment: try to use width:100%; height:auto;

Comment: Ahs N: Can you please create an answer for this, and I will mark it as the solution? ui-datepicker-trigger was forcing the size to 33px for some reason. when I overwrote the settings, it was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your style may help you

```
input[type="text"].datePickerWithImage
{
width:17px;
height:17px;
}
```

Comment: This seems to affect only the actual input text field length. The icon remains stretched..

Comment: you can add .ui-datepicker{width:17px; height:17px;} may it's work for you